# JSONObject's names() method returns inconsistent results

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm trying to get [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)'s high level branches by using [names()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()) method(which is DD.MM.yyyy dates in this example) then storing this result as ArrayList after running standard for loop then sending it to ViewPager adapter, so this ArrayList has to be sorted.

But the problem is it's not sorted on older version of Android.

Here are my setDayList and getDayList method:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getDayList() {
    if (mGunListesi == null) {
        setDayList();
    }
    return mGunListesi;
}

private static void setDayList() {
    // getAylikListeJson() returns main JSONObject
    JSONArray array = getAylikListeJson().names();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        String date = null;
        try {
            date = array.getString(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (dayAvailable(date)) {
            arrayList.add(date);
        }
    }
    mGunListesi = arrayList;
}
```

Result of getDayList().toString() on Android 4.4:

```
D/List: JSON dates: [26.02.2016, 15.02.2016, 02.02.2016, 11.02.2016, 04.02.2016, 02.03.2016, 01.03.2016, 01.02.2016, 05.02.2016, 08.02.2016, 23.02.2016, 18.02.2016, 29.02.2016, 10.02.2016, 24.02.2016, 03.03.2016, 16.02.2016, 04.03.2016, 22.02.2016, 09.02.2016, 17.02.2016, 19.02.2016, 03.02.2016, 25.02.2016, 12.02.2016]
```

Result of getDayList().toString() on Android 6.0:

```
D/List: JSON dates: [01.02.2016, 02.02.2016, 03.02.2016, 04.02.2016, 05.02.2016, 08.02.2016, 09.02.2016, 10.02.2016, 11.02.2016, 12.02.2016, 15.02.2016, 16.02.2016, 17.02.2016, 18.02.2016, 19.02.2016, 22.02.2016, 23.02.2016, 24.02.2016, 25.02.2016, 26.02.2016, 29.02.2016, 01.03.2016, 02.03.2016, 03.03.2016, 04.03.2016]
```

And the JSON file:

```html
{
    "01.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 7,
            "ad": "Etli Taze Fasulye",
            "kalori": 262,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/etlitazefasulye.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 17,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Bulgur Pilavı",
            "kalori": 352,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelibulgurpilavi.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 26,
            "ad": "Cacık",
            "kalori": 97,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/cacik.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 144,
            "ad": "Meyve (Elma)",
            "kalori": 142,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/meyveelma1.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 193,
            "ad": "Fırın Bamya",
            "kalori": 77,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/bamya.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "02.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 73,
            "ad": "Peynirli Börek",
            "kalori": 362,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/borek.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 163,
            "ad": "Tavuk Çorbası",
            "kalori": 1,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/resimyok.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 11,
            "ad": "Ayran",
            "kalori": 60,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/ayran.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 63,
            "ad": "Meyve (Armut)",
            "kalori": 128,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/meyvearmut.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 245,
            "ad": "Türlü (Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 108,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/etsizturlu.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "03.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 25,
            "ad": "Soslu Fırın Tavuk",
            "kalori": 535,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/soslufirintavuk.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 20,
            "ad": "Mercimek Çorba",
            "kalori": 244,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/mahlutacorba.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 222,
            "ad": "Yoğurtlu Revani",
            "kalori": 595,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/revani.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 275,
            "ad": "Marul Salata",
            "kalori": 93,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/mevsimsalata.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 37,
            "ad": "Zeytinyağlı Barbunya",
            "kalori": 371,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/barbunya.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "04.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 1,
            "ad": "Terbiyeli Köfte",
            "kalori": 295,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/terbiyelikofte.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 9,
            "ad": "Soslu Makarna",
            "kalori": 304,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/soslumakarna.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 13,
            "ad": "Havuç Salata",
            "kalori": 105,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salata.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 87,
            "ad": "Fırın Bezelye (Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 190,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/firinbezelye.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "05.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 49,
            "ad": "Etli Kuru Fasulye",
            "kalori": 340,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/etlikurufasulye.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 2,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Pirinç Pilavı",
            "kalori": 367,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelipilav.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 24,
            "ad": "Salatalık Turşusu",
            "kalori": 7,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salataliktursusu.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 147,
            "ad": "Patlıcan Güveç(Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 292,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/patlicanguvec.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "08.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 143,
            "ad": "Kıymalı Bezelye",
            "kalori": 390,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/kiymalibezelye.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 17,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Bulgur Pilavı",
            "kalori": 352,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelibulgurpilavi.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 144,
            "ad": "Meyve (Elma)",
            "kalori": 142,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/meyveelma1.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 37,
            "ad": "Zeytinyağlı Barbunya",
            "kalori": 371,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/barbunya.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "09.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 117,
            "ad": "Mantarlı Çoban Kavurma",
            "kalori": 278,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/mantarlicobankavurma.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 2,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Pirinç Pilavı",
            "kalori": 367,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelipilav.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 154,
            "ad": "Sütlü İrmik Tatlısı",
            "kalori": 309,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sutluirmiktatlisi.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 29,
            "ad": "Marul Salata(1)",
            "kalori": 93,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/marulsalata.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 266,
            "ad": "Sulu Patates(Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 444,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sulupatates.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "10.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 41,
            "ad": "Sini Köfte",
            "kalori": 460,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sinikofte.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 32,
            "ad": "Nohutlu Bulgur Pilavı",
            "kalori": 362,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/nohutlubulgurpilavi.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 145,
            "ad": "Meyve (Muz)",
            "kalori": 90,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/muz.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 190,
            "ad": "Ispanak Kavurma",
            "kalori": 42,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/ispanakkavurma.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "11.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 179,
            "ad": "Sebzeli Tavuk Tava",
            "kalori": 610,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sebzelitavuktava.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 2,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Pirinç Pilavı",
            "kalori": 367,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelipilav.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 11,
            "ad": "Ayran",
            "kalori": 60,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/ayran.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 13,
            "ad": "Havuç Salata",
            "kalori": 105,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salata.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 282,
            "ad": "Patlıcan Musakka(Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 292,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/patlicanmusakkaetsiz.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "12.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 5,
            "ad": "Soslu Dalyan Köfte",
            "kalori": 246,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sosludalyankofte.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 19,
            "ad": "Şehriye Çorba",
            "kalori": 126,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyecorba.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 24,
            "ad": "Salatalık Turşusu",
            "kalori": 7,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salataliktursusu.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 234,
            "ad": "Üzüm Hoşafı",
            "kalori": 328,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/hosaf.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 146,
            "ad": "Karnabahar Kızartma",
            "kalori": 184,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/karnabahar.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "15.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 77,
            "ad": "Arap Tava",
            "kalori": 234,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/araptava.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 18,
            "ad": "Peynirli Makarna",
            "kalori": 341,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/peynirlimakarna.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 155,
            "ad": "Şalgam",
            "kalori": 20,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salgam.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 144,
            "ad": "Meyve (Elma)",
            "kalori": 142,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/meyveelma1.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 245,
            "ad": "Türlü (Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 108,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/etsizturlu.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "16.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 78,
            "ad": "Buhara Kebap",
            "kalori": 459,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/buharakebap.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 17,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Bulgur Pilavı",
            "kalori": 352,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelibulgurpilavi.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 24,
            "ad": "Salatalık Turşusu",
            "kalori": 7,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salataliktursusu.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 3,
            "ad": "Zeytinyağlı Taze Fasülye",
            "kalori": 153,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/zeytinyaglifasulye.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "17.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 235,
            "ad": "Çıtır Tavuk-Par.Patates",
            "kalori": 250,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/citirtavukparmakpatates.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 273,
            "ad": "Domates Çorba(1)",
            "kalori": 245,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/domatescorba.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 13,
            "ad": "Havuç Salata",
            "kalori": 105,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salata.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 222,
            "ad": "Yoğurtlu Revani",
            "kalori": 595,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/revani.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 188,
            "ad": "Zeytinyağlı Pırasa",
            "kalori": 114,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/zeytinyaglipirasa.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "18.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 88,
            "ad": "Etli Patates(Sulu)",
            "kalori": 379,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/etlipatates.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 17,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Bulgur Pilavı",
            "kalori": 352,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelibulgurpilavi.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 267,
            "ad": "Meyve(Armut-Deveci)",
            "kalori": 128,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/armut.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 87,
            "ad": "Fırın Bezelye (Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 190,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/firinbezelye.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "19.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 22,
            "ad": "Etli Nohut",
            "kalori": 373,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/etlinohut.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 2,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Pirinç Pilavı",
            "kalori": 367,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelipilav.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 144,
            "ad": "Meyve (Elma)",
            "kalori": 142,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/meyveelma1.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 70,
            "ad": "Patlıcan Kızartma",
            "kalori": 294,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/patlicankizartma.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "22.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 97,
            "ad": "Hasan Paşa Köfte (Püreli)",
            "kalori": 480,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/hasanpasakofte.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 9,
            "ad": "Soslu Makarna",
            "kalori": 304,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/soslumakarna.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 11,
            "ad": "Ayran",
            "kalori": 60,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/ayran.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 267,
            "ad": "Meyve(Armut-Deveci)",
            "kalori": 128,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/armut.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 193,
            "ad": "Fırın Bamya",
            "kalori": 77,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/bamya.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "23.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 205,
            "ad": "Barbunya",
            "kalori": 371,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/barbunya.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 36,
            "ad": "Etli Pirinç Pilavı",
            "kalori": 312,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/etlipilav.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 13,
            "ad": "Havuç Salata",
            "kalori": 105,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salata.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 246,
            "ad": "Kabak Kızartma",
            "kalori": 1,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/kabakkizartma.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "24.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 49,
            "ad": "Etli Kuru Fasulye",
            "kalori": 340,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/etlikurufasulye.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 17,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Bulgur Pilavı",
            "kalori": 352,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelibulgurpilavi.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 64,
            "ad": "Türlü Turşu",
            "kalori": 10,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/turlutursu.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 134,
            "ad": "Yüzük Mantı Çorba",
            "kalori": 148,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yuzukmanti.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "25.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 278,
            "ad": "Tavuk Izgara(1)",
            "kalori": 620,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/tavuk.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 20,
            "ad": "Mercimek Çorba",
            "kalori": 244,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/mahlutacorba.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 4,
            "ad": "Muhallebi",
            "kalori": 240,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/Muhallebi.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 13,
            "ad": "Havuç Salata",
            "kalori": 105,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salata.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 217,
            "ad": "Patatesli Börek",
            "kalori": 544,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/borek.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "26.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 40,
            "ad": "Bahçevan Kebap",
            "kalori": 357,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/bahcevankebap.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 2,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Pirinç Pilavı",
            "kalori": 367,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelipilav.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 154,
            "ad": "Sütlü İrmik Tatlısı",
            "kalori": 309,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sutluirmiktatlisi.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 275,
            "ad": "Marul Salata",
            "kalori": 93,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/mevsimsalata.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 190,
            "ad": "Ispanak Kavurma",
            "kalori": 42,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/ispanakkavurma.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "29.02.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 143,
            "ad": "Kıymalı Bezelye",
            "kalori": 390,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/kiymalibezelye.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 2,
            "ad": "Şehriyeli Pirinç Pilavı",
            "kalori": 367,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sehriyelipilav.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 10,
            "ad": "Yoğurt",
            "kalori": 118,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/yogurt.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 64,
            "ad": "Türlü Turşu",
            "kalori": 10,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/turlutursu.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 37,
            "ad": "Zeytinyağlı Barbunya",
            "kalori": 371,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/barbunya.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "01.03.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 44,
            "ad": "İçli Köfte",
            "kalori": 700,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/iclikofte.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 35,
            "ad": "Mahluta Çorba",
            "kalori": 245,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/mahluta.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 248,
            "ad": "Halka Tatlı",
            "kalori": 642,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/halkatatli.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 275,
            "ad": "Marul Salata",
            "kalori": 93,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/mevsimsalata.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 202,
            "ad": "Karışık Kızartma(Soslu)",
            "kalori": 224,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/karisikkizartma.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "02.03.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 16,
            "ad": "Çoban Kavurma",
            "kalori": 309,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/cobankavurma.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 32,
            "ad": "Nohutlu Bulgur Pilavı",
            "kalori": 362,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/nohutlubulgurpilavi.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 11,
            "ad": "Ayran",
            "kalori": 60,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/ayran.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 144,
            "ad": "Meyve (Elma)",
            "kalori": 142,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/meyveelma1.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 132,
            "ad": "Kuru Fasülye(Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 1,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/kurufasulyeetsiz.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "03.03.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 41,
            "ad": "Sini Köfte",
            "kalori": 460,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/sinikofte.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 18,
            "ad": "Peynirli Makarna",
            "kalori": 341,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/peynirlimakarna.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 155,
            "ad": "Şalgam",
            "kalori": 20,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/salgam.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 148,
            "ad": "Meyve (Portakal)",
            "kalori": 171,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/portakal.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 3,
            "ad": "Zeytinyağlı Taze Fasülye",
            "kalori": 153,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/zeytinyaglifasulye.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    },
    "04.03.2016": {
        "yemek1": {
            "id": 180,
            "ad": "Tavuk Pane+ Parmak Pat.",
            "kalori": 468,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/panetavuk.png"
        },
        "yemek2": {
            "id": 229,
            "ad": "Beşamel Soslu Havuç Çorbası",
            "kalori": 190,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/havuccorbasi.png"
        },
        "yemek3": {
            "id": 29,
            "ad": "Marul Salata(1)",
            "kalori": 93,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/marulsalata.png"
        },
        "yemek4": {
            "id": 110,
            "ad": "Keşgül",
            "kalori": 381,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/keskul.png"
        },
        "yemek5": {
            "id": 147,
            "ad": "Patlıcan Güveç(Etsiz)",
            "kalori": 292,
            "gorsel": "/yemekler/patlicanguvec.png"
        },
        "durum": 1,
        "gun": 1
    }
}
```

So am I missing something? Why does the Android 6.0 returns the result in order but older versions returns in random order?

**Edit**: Thanks for wero's precise reply, I fixed the problem by sorting ArrayList on pre-Lollipop devices by adding following code to the setDailyList method:

```
        if (Utils.preLollipop()) {
            Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<String>() {
            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtils.JSON_DATE_FORMAT); // JSON_DATE_FORMAT = "DD.MM.yyyy"

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                try {
                    return format.parse(o1).compareTo(format.parse(o2));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I can only guess that it's an implementation detail on newer Android versions, as JSON objects are by definition unordered. To fix this you should look at the code that creates your JSON and make it use an array (which *are* ordered) of dates instead. Or sort the `ArrayList` afterwards, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Androids `JSONObject` internally uses a map to store its name-value-pairs.

Initially it was a `java.util.Map` and by default initialized with a `HashMap` which does not guarantee order. [Later](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/319bef83054979209a01b484af34ce1087d28559%5E!/#F0) this was changed and `JSONObject` now uses a order-preserving `LinkedHashMap`.

Also note that the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) defines:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs